# where are the error and warning codes for compiler in VS2019

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, warnings

where are the descriptions for error and warning codes for compiler in VS2019 ?
Eg
what does this mean, and how do I fix it ?

```
Warning G77590269   ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]   C:\SDKC4.1.0\SDK\Projects\VT7_FWMCT_210913\Release\Linux\VT7_FWMCT_210913   C:\SDKC4.1.0\SDK\Projects\VT7_FWMCT_210913\source\UI\Screens\Source2.cpp    195
```

and errors like :-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   G6555C181   'Pme' does not name a type  C:\SDKC4.1.0\SDK\Projects\VT7_FWMCT_210913\Release\Linux\VT7_FWMCT_210913   C:\SDKC4.1.0\SDK\Projects\VT7_FWMCT_210913\source\UI\Screens\Source2.cpp    33
```

I have tried to declare a struct as the type for Pme[].
Eg

```
typedef struct
{
    char* outputpinno[16];
    char* outputname[16];
    char* inputpinno[16];
    char* inputname[16];
    char* Analogpinno[8];
    char* Analogname[8];
    char* CanName[8];
} pme_T;
```

Then I initialise the array with :-

```
pme_T Pme[2];


Pme[0].outputpinno[16] = {
    "J1-12",
    "J1-1",
    "J2-12",
    "J2-1",
    "J3-12",
    "J3-1",
    "J4-12",
    "J4-1",
    "J1-7",
    "J1-6",
    "J2-7",
    "J2-6",
    "J3-7",
    "J3-6",
    "J4-7",
    "J4-6",
};

how do I find out more about Error and Warning codes ?
- totally confused.
```

Comment: These don't look like MS compiler error codes. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Reference to Microsoft compiler errors / warnings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/c-cpp-build-errors?view=msvc-160